# How to disable a button when program starts

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a button to be disabled when the program first starts, and only enabled when text is present in a particular text box.

This is the code I have:

```
If quantityTextBox.Text = "" Then
        clearButton.Enabled = False
    Else
        clearButton.Enabled = True
    End If
```

The only issue I'm having is figuring out what sub to put it under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to the changed event for the textbox.  In VS double clicking the textbox in the form designer will initialise the event handler and drop you into the codebehind automatically.

You also don't need the If statement.  You can do this on one line with:

```
clearButton.Enabled = quantityTextBox.Text <> ""
```

Comment: Hmm, The clear button doesn't disable until I put in an input and then clear it.

Comment: Select the button and hit F4.  You'll see the property window for the button.  Set Enabled to false.